# Constrain a background from sliding past leftmost edge of your screen

Tags: css, background, html

I'm sorry, I don't know how to more clearly word this question, but my webpage `background-position` is currently set to `center`. When I resize the window, the it stays in the very center, and when the window is smaller than the background image, the image STAYS centered, so both the left and the right edges become cut off. The problem I'm having with this is that my div content boxes will stay in the center when I use `margin:auto;`, but when the window is resized down to a width smaller than the `width:700px;`, the left-most edge of the box stays within sight while the right-most hides outside of the window frame. It's really difficult for me to explain, I'm sorry if I'm unclear. I'm very new to web development. Here's screenshot examples:
http://puu.sh/7jnNV.jpg : Good! Everything is centered and aligned
http://puu.sh/7jnPO.jpg : Bad! The background image remains centered to the width of the window, but the div box stops at the left-most edge, and then runs off the other side:
http://puu.sh/7jnSN.jpg : Since the width is fixed, it runs off the side of the background because it's offset from the center of the background.

Here is the webpage code thusfar:

```
<head>
<style>
html, body {
    min-height: 100%
}
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url(banner.png), url(footer.png), url(filler.png);
    background-position: center top, center bottom, center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-y;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<style>
div.content
{
width:700px;
padding:10px;
border:2px solid #004688;
margin:auto;
margin-top:400px;
margin-bottom: 135px;
}
</style>
<div class="content">test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</div>
</body>
```

So I figure the easiest fix is to stop the background from sliding past the left-most edge of your screen, and that way everything stays centered relative to eachother. But I don't know how to do that, and googling is unhelpful since I don't know wtf I'm even talking about lol ;c

Answer (score 0):

Apply the background inside a container div.

Height and width of the container div will be same as the background.

Now center the container div both horizontally and vertically using CSS.

Comment: I'll give it a try, I gave a quick attempt at putting the background inside a div, but I think I did it wrong because I couldn't get it to work. It makes sense that it should work your way, so I'll keep trying.

Comment: Divs have no height by default. Probably your container div is blank or no height applied. You must add a height to the container div.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Perhaps use `background-size` to dynamically scale the image? You can use `cover` or `100%`